# How to make multiple submit buttons work on Oracle Apex without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to make an Apex website functional with Javascript disabled. The website makes use of sometimes multiple submit buttons on a single page. It uses Javascript function apex.submit(request name, e.g. 'SAVE' or 'CANCEL') to submit a request on a click of a button, which then can be differentiated based on its name. Is there any way to submit specific request, i.e. 'SAVE' without the use of Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't I'm afraid.  I often have to build APEX pages that work when Javascript is disabled and one of the limitations that imposes is: only 1 submit button per page.  There is no way to get the Request value of the button that submits the page when Javascript is disabled, so if you have more than one they will be indistinguishable.